# Remove Values from Grafana

Tags: grafana, zabbix, icmp

I have a scenario like this pic, where I get the status from my hosts.
I have a few dozens of hosts so I would like to apply some filters, like showing only hosts that had problems during certain period.
I found one option, that I used in this example, that is the remove[below/above]value, but it only removes the value itself, not the entire column, the host itself.
Basically, considering this example, I would like this host(second bottom-up), that didn't have 1 value during this last week, did not appear on this screen.
Is there a way? I hope the question isn't very confusing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `removeBelowValues` function removes the values from the serie, but can't remove the serie.

Depending on your data, you can turn the series to rows, then remove rows using "Filter Data by Values" transformation. See https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#filter-data-by-value

Example:

[image: example remove by value from zabbix time serie]